# PHP Client Socket blocks reading after write

Tags: java, php, sockets

I am programming a server socket for java that takes data from a client socket, processes them and sends a response back.

At the current state I am able to send data and process it, but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how to send the processed data from the server socket to the client socket. I already tried using the example provided from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php), but that just somehow just blocks the sending of my data. I also tried to only read or write and that worked like a charm.

My server socket (java) looks as follows:

```
public class TcpListener {

  public static String clientSentence;
  private static ServerSocket serverSocket;


  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(49654);
    Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
   while(true)
   {
      //read
      int reportId = read(connectionSocket);
      //write
      write(connectionSocket, reportId);
   }
   //connectionSocket.close();
  }

  public static int read(Socket connectionSocket) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();  
    System.out.println(clientSentence);
    Report r = new Report(clientSentence);
    int reportId = r.main();
    inFromClient.close();
    return reportId;
  }

  public static void write(Socket connectionSocket, int id) throws IOException{
    PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), true);          
    System.out.println(id);
    outToClient.println(id);
    outToClient.flush();
    outToClient.close();
  }
}
```

and my client socket (php):

```
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

$host = "localhost";
$port = 49654;

if (($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) === false) {
    echo "\nsocket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
} else {
    echo "\nAttempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...\n";
    if (($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    } else {
        socket_set_nonblock($socket);
        echo "Sending data...\n";
        $sresult = socket_send($socket, $message."\r\n", strlen($message), MSG_DONTROUTE);
        if ($sresult === false) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error($socket);
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
            die("error sending data. " . $errormsg. "($errorcode)");
        }
        echo "OK\n";
        echo "Reading response:\n\n";
        while(socket_recv ( $socket , $buf , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE){
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

            die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        }
        echo $buf;
    }
    echo "close";
    socket_close($socket);
}
```

The following error message is being displayed:

```
Warning: socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [10045]: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object
referenced. <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\api\select\getApps.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
Could not receive data: [10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.
```

Where line 75 is the `while` loop.

I would appreciate any help on how to fix my problem.

Comment: please replace `socket_send($socket, $message."\r\n", strlen($message), MSG_DONTROUTE);` with `$sresult = socket_send($socket, $message."\r\n", strlen($message), MSG_DONTROUTE); if ($sresult === false) { $errorcode = socket_last_error($socket);$errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode); die("error sending data. " . $errormsg. "($errorcode)") }` so we can see if it actually returns an error.

Comment: @Cemal does not return anything because it is blocked

Comment: can you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your php script to see if there's an error that you miss. I'm assuming there's an error you miss as according to your code, at least sthg should return.

Comment: @Cemal it now displays an error message, I changed the post